# Checkbox classList Toggle

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use a custom slider with an input type=checkbox to toggle between dark-mode and light-mode. It is not working with the javascript code I have.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', themeChange);
    
    function themeChange(){
      if (checkbox.checked == true){
        document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('dark-mode');
      } else {
        document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('light-mode');
      }
    }
```

```css
.dark-mode {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .light-mode {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
<label class="switch">
       <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" >
       <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>

      <body id='body'>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please correct your variable. You have defined variable above as checkbox and used checkBox in if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toggle` won't remove different the classes, you have to `add` and `remove`, please check the working code below.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', themeChange);

function themeChange(){
  
  if (checkbox.checked == true){
    document.getElementById('body').classList.add('dark-mode');
    document.getElementById('body').classList.remove('light-mode');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('body').classList.add('light-mode');
    document.getElementById('body').classList.remove('dark-mode');
  }
}
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.light-mode {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
   <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" >
   <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<body id='body'>
    Theme switcher
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.toggle()` will remove and add one single class. Try it this way instead

```
function themeChange(){
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    document.getElementById('body').classList.add('dark-mode');
    document.getElementById('body').classList.remove('light-mode');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('body').classList.remove('dark-mode');
    document.getElementById('body').classList.add('light-mode');
}
```

Comment: You can't use **.addClass('class-name')** in pure javascript so you can use for add **.add('class-name')** and for remove use **.remove('class-name')**

Comment: true, I mixed up jQuery syntax, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one?

```js
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
      if (checkbox.checked == true){
        document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('dark-mode',true);
        document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('light-mode',false);
      } else {
        document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('dark-mode',false);
        document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('light-mode',true);
      }
    } )
```

```css
    .dark-mode {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .light-mode {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
    <label class="switch">
       <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" >
       <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>

      <body id='body'>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way instead

```
var checkBox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
let body =  document.getElementById('body');
let i =2;


checkbox.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
if (i%2==0){
   div.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
  } else {
    div.classList.toggle('light-mode');

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

console.log(checkbox.valueOf());
checkbox.addEventListener('change', themeChange);

function themeChange(){
    if (checkbox.checked == true){
        document.getElementById('body').classList.add('dark-mode');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('body').classList.add('light-mode');
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can check below snippet.

```js
var body = document.getElementById('body');
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', themeChange);

function themeChange(){
  if (checkbox.checked){
    body.classList.remove('light-mode');
    body.classList.add('dark-mode');
  } else {
    body.classList.add('light-mode');
    body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
  }
}
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.light-mode {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body id='body'>

<label class="switch">
   <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" >
   <span class="slider round"></span> Dark/Light Mode
</label>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some problem:

1. You must wrap all elements in the `<body>` element.
2. You don't need to give the id attribute to select the `<body>` element.
3. Before you define a function, you should not bind it to an event. First define the function then bind the predefined function to an event.
4. For the `toggle()` method to work properly, you must apply the `.light-mode` class style to the `<body>` element by default.
5. You don't need to check the checkbox as it is a toggle check.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

function themeChange() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("light-mode");
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode"); 
}

checkbox.addEventListener('change', themeChange);
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.light-mode {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!-- By default, the "light-mode" style was applied to the <body> element. -->
<body class="light-mode">
  <label class="switch">
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" >
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</body>
```

To apply the `toggle()` method to multiple class styles simultaneously, you can update the `themeChange()` method as follows:

```js
function themeChange() {
  ["light-mode", "dark-mode"].map(cn => document.body.classList.toggle(cn));
}
```